# Issue with functions: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

Just playing around on codewars and came across this problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5514e5b77e6b2f38e0000ca9/train/python

Now I built this function (in Sublime):

```
def up_array(arr):

    is_valid = []

    if len(arr) > 0:
        is_valid.append(1)
    else:
        is_valid.append(0)

    for x in arr:
        if x < 0:
            is_valid.append(0)
        else:
            is_valid.append(1)

    if 0 not in is_valid:
        arr = int(''.join(str(n) for n in arr))
        arr += 1
        arr = str(arr)
        arr = [int(n) for n in arr]
        return arr
    else:
        return None



print(up_array([4,3,2,5])
```

and I keep getting `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

***BUT*** when I run the same code outside the function:

```
arr = [4,3,2,5]

is_valid = []
if len(arr) > 0:
    is_valid.append(1)
else:
    is_valid.append(0)

for x in arr:
    if x < 0:
        is_valid.append(0)
    else:
        is_valid.append(1)

if 0 not in is_valid:
    arr = int(''.join(str(n) for n in arr))
    arr += 1
    arr = str(arr)
    arr = [int(n) for n in arr]
    print(arr)
else:
    print(None)
```

The code runs great through various tests. Any thoughts as to what the issue with the function is?
I have tried re-tabbing & re-writing but when I put code inside a function. I started getting this parsing error.

I don't want to put too much time into the issue but it will linger in the back of my mind so any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a closing paren for `print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` error is caused because of missing parenthesis on last line `print(up_array([4,3,2,5])`

It should be like this:

```
print(up_array([4,3,2,5]))
```